# How to reference the mail which triggered the outlook macro?

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, qtp

I am designing a QTP framework which in which the automation engineer sends an email in order to start the test suite execution (The email can be scheduled using MS Outlook)

As soon as the trigger mail is received, the **attachment should be downloaded** and QTP should be launched (automatically) using appropriate settings by the Outlook Macro

But in the above scenario **I want to download the attachment of the mail and move the mail to a different folder which triggered the macro.**

Is there any way to reference the mail which triggered the macro?

Currently this is what I am doing.

```html
Sub TestSuiteInitialilzer(mail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objDestFolder = Inbox.Folders("RAN")
    FileName = "C:\Email Attachments\" & mail.Attachments.Item.FileName
    'Download the attachment
    Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
    'Move the mail to another folder
    mail.Move objDestFolder
    launchQTP = "C:\Unlock.vbs"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ‘Launch QTP
    objShell.Run launchQTP  
    objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you setup the trigger? Most likely you can refer to any item in Outlook using `.EntryID`. If you use application level event trigger to execute the macro, have a read on http://www.slipstick.com/developer/processing-incoming-e-mails-with-macros/

Comment: The mail is the trigger. Automation engineer sends an email in order to start the test suite execution. The mail will have a particular subject e.g. ‘RunQTPMasterDriverScript’ and an attachment which contains path of the test scripts and run indicator. A rule in Outlook is created to monitor the inbox and call the macro when a mail with subject as ‘RunQTPMasterDriverScript’ is arrived. The macro should download the attachment, move the mail from one folder to another .

Comment: I want the macro to download the attachment and move the mail from one folder to another. How can this be achieved? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: My intention was if we can directly reference the mail which triggered the macro, we don't have to go through the entire email collection of the inbox to search the mail with the particular subject 'RunQTPMasterDriverScript'. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: What have you done so far in code regarding the receiving side? The event on the receiving side is the "trigger" that PatricK asked for.

Comment: @JdevKamath What you have setup sounds like a Rule in Outlook to run a macro when certain conditions are met. Bare in mind that this only works if your Outlook session is running and there isn't any issue with it. I have macros that work in similar way. And yes, once you have the mail item, you can save all attachments, move it to a sub folder in your mailbox (to indicate it has been processed), etc. I will respond some code when I have free time today. I don't have QTP, how do you execute it?

Comment: @PatricK I am running a VBScript to configure and launch the QTP. I have given the code in description that I am currently using but I have no idea whether it is working fine or not! Whenever I try to run the code, VBA is telling me to create a new macro. I guess this is happening due to the parameter that is passed. Do you have any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps to skip checking the whole Inbox until a match. Keep yours just in case you need to run it manually for the first matching item.

1) Add code below (altered to use cscript.exe):

```
Sub TestSuiteInitialilzer_Rules(ByRef oMail As MailItem)
    Const FileName = "C:\Email Attachments\"
    For Each Atmt In oMail.Attachments
        'Download the attachment
        Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName & Atmt.Filename
    Next Atmt
    ' Move the Mail to objDestFolder
    oMail.Move objDestFolder
    'launchQTP = "C:\Unlock.vbs"
    launchQTP = "cscript.exe //nologo C:\Unlock.vbs"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'QTP will be launched with the neccassary configurations through the vb script
    objShell.Run launchQTP
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

2) Add Outlook Rule (Apply rule on messages I receive) on top of your existing one. Better to turn off your existing one.

[image: OutlookRule]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!   Why do we need cscript? Can't we a VBS file using WShell object through the macro? And whenever I try to run the code, VBA is telling me to create a new macro. I guess this is happening due to the parameter that is passed. Do you have any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Since I don't know whats in the vbs file, if it ever uses wscript.echo, cscript will display it and let the code running. wscript however, will pause until OK is pressed. You cannot have 2 Subs of the same name. Add "_Rule" to the new one.

Comment: Okay. Is there something that I can do to associate the macro with the rule (and activate the rule) when the outlook restarts or will it be associated automatically?

Comment: Once you have setup the Outlook Rule, it is activated until Outlook decides that the macro has an error.

Comment: Just one more question, any idea how do I point to the 'Inbox' under personal folder?
Mailbox - Jai dev 
-Deleted items
-Draft
-Inbox
-Junk Email
-Outbox
-Sent Item
Personal Folders
-Deleted items
-Draft
-Inbox
-Junk Email
-Outbox
-Sent Item
Mailbox - Bill Jobs
-Deleted items
-Draft
-Inbox
-Junk Email
-Outbox
-Sent Item

Comment: Check the example out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863652(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define a VBA macro sub which accepts a MailItem as a parameter. The source object will be passed to the sub and you don't need to search it in the Inbox folder. For example:

```
Public Sub Text(mail as Outlook.MailItem)
    ' do something with the mail object
End Sub
```

You can access attachments using the *Attachments* property of the MailItem class. The *Move* method allows to move the item to another folder.

Comment: mail as Outlook.MailItem - In this statement does the 'mail' refer to the mail item which triggered the macro?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I have given the code in description that I am currently using but I have no idea whether it is working fine or not! Whenever I try to run the code, VBA is telling me to create a new macro. I guess this is happening due to the parameter that is passed. Do you have any idea what's going wrong here?