# In VBA code for outlook rule, how to use/reference the email which caused the trigger

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have created a rule to run a script for when emails have certain headers. 
My script is trying to get the excel table content from the email and save that locally, to be further processed.

The below is a snippet I found and used: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22631e7e-53df-47c4-b625-22c9e935f02b/copy-a-table-from-body-of-an-email-to-excel-spreadsheet?forum=outlookdev

It works when I use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Item`, aka on the email that is open at the moment of running.

However, I wish to perform the below action on the email  that triggered it. I tried to follow [How to reference the mail which triggered the outlook macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060246/how-to-reference-the-mail-which-triggered-the-outlook-macro) and their logic ByRef, but it did not work for me.

Can someone please advise on how I can get the table text by using GetInspector.WordEditor logic below on the trigger email? Thank you!

```
Sub getDailyCollMV(ByRef Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim r As Object  'As Word.Range
Dim doc As Object 'As Word.Document
Dim xlApp As Object, wkb As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wks As Object
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)

For Each ItemVal In Application.ActiveExplorer.Item
Set doc = ItemVal.GetInspector.WordEditor
    For x = 1 To doc.tables.Count
     Set r = doc.tables(x)
        r.Range.Copy
       wks.Paste
       wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1).Select
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Item  is passed to you as a parameter. Why are yo uusing "for each with Application.ActiveExplorer.Item? Did you mean Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection. You don't need that anyway.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko my understanding was that Application.ActiveExplorer will choose the email that is open, not necessarily the triggered one

Comment: Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1) is the currently selected email in the active explorer. Nothing more, nothing less. The message does not trigger any macros. The user does.

Comment: Sorry! maybe I was not clear. I setup a rule in outlook, which will trigger running the script if a message's header contains some text. For the message under that rule, I want to process it in my macro, not the currently selected email in active explorer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant - the item is passed as a parameter - Item in your sub above.

Comment: Hm I thought that was the only way for the macro to be picked up by Outlook's rule 'run script' function(by adding Item As Outlook.MailItem in the Sub definition) . Any tips on what to do? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, Outlook forces you to provide a function that takes the item that triggered the rule as a parameter. This is done on purpose so you would not have to guess. You must use the Item object passed as a parameter. Forget about Application.ActiveExplorer etc. Just use the Item parameter.

Comment: Dimitry's answer is short but completely correct.  Recently I created a long answer to another questioner who, like you, was confused about the different ways of selecting an email for processing.  That answer included one macro that processes a selected email plus descriptions and macros for the four different selection methods.  The processing macro is no use to you but the four descriptions might help.

Comment: Thank you guys,appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the lines

```
For Each ItemVal In Application.ActiveExplorer.Item
Set doc = ItemVal.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

with

```
Set doc = Item.GetInspector.WordEditor
```